# Creating list in one line from variables with distinct names and values in R

Tags: r, list

this is my first question on this forum so I hope I follow all the right procedures.

I was wondering if it's possible to create a list in R from a set of variables with distinct names and values in one line. Specifically, I already have a list `list_cond <- list("foo1", "foo2", "foo3",...)` and a list of lists `list_vals <- list(list(1, 2, 3), list(4, 5, 6), list(7, 8, 9))` and would like to create a list `new_list <- list(f("foo1")=2, f("foo2")=5, f("foo3")=8)` procedurally where a string modifying function `f` is applied to each element of `list_cond` before it is used as a name for the corresponding element which is indexed from `list_vals`. Is there a way to do this in a single line?

I found `sapply` as a method in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30351866/name-list-elements-based-on-variable-names-r) by using `USE.NAMES=TRUE` but it seems to only generate the names from the function passed in, and the values are just the same as the names. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14801035/growing-a-list-with-variable-names-in-r) is also related, but I specifically want to generate both the names and the values in the same line, not just add names to the values.

If doing this in one line isn't possible, are there any specific methods that are efficient as opposed to just creating the list and using some `apply` function to add the names later?

EDIT: as this will be running on a specific server which doesn't have a lot of R packages, so built in functions would be preferable

Comment: Do you need `map(list_vals, ~ set_names(.x, unlist(list_cond)))`

Comment: I wasn't able to test it as I am running R on a server without many libraries. I updated my post to put this detail in. Is there a way to do this with built in R functions?

Comment: Based on the expected output, are you extracting only the second element

Comment: If that is the case `map(list_vals, pluck, 2) %>% set_names(paste0(unlist(list_cond), "_", seq_along(list_vals)))`  Or with `base R` `setNames(lapply(list_vals, '[[', 2), paste0(unlist(list_cond), "_", seq_along(list_vals)))`

Comment: Your *new_list* names seems counter intuitive. Why `1_1` suffix patterns for the second element in each of the nested elements? And is the third name missing a number for *foo3_3*?

Comment: I am getting an error: `could not find function %>%`

Comment: My bad, I wrote my example badly and will update my post. I just meant that I'm applying some function on to each string. In reality my program is actually reading values from a tkentry textvariable using `tclvalue` but I wanted to make it simpler.

Comment: @akrun it worked! that's what I'm looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We extract the second element of the `list` and then set the names of the `list` with 'list_cond' (is a `list` so `unlist` it to create a `vector`)

```
setNames(lapply(list_vals, '[[', 2), 
          paste0(unlist(list_cond), "_", seq_along(list_vals)))
```

---

A tidyverse approach would be

```
library(tidyverse)
map(list_vals, pluck, 2) %>% 
     set_names(paste0(unlist(list_cond), "_", seq_along(list_vals)))
```

#### data

```
list_cond <- list("foo1", "foo2", "foo3")
list_vals <- list(list(1, 2, 3), list(4, 5, 6), list(7, 8, 9))
```