# R output named list

Tags: r, list, names

I often write functions which return named lists as arguments. Here's a simple example:

```
func <- function() {
    x <- rnorm(10)
    y <- runif(10)
    out <- list(x = x, y = y)
    return(out)
}
```

The command `list(x = x, y = y)` is my current solution for having a list whose name is the same as the objects it contains, otherwise the output will have names `[[1]]` and `[[2]]`. My problem is that this can get annoying and rather inelegant with longer and more complicated examples.

**I am wondering if there's a better solution that doesn't require me having to write the name of each listed element twice.** I've seen a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30351866/1169233), but found the accepted answer too convoluted for my case.

Comment: `func <- function() list(x=rnorm(10), y=runif(10))`

Comment: @jogo thank you for your input; I guess I should have mentioned that I am aware of this alternative, but it can also look pretty ugly if the list elements are more complicated (imagine long equations or big data frames), not to mention that there might be a reason to keep `x` and `y` assigned and located at an earlier part of the function.

Answer (score 6):

**1) data.frame** For the function in the question this would work to output a named list with names `x` and `y`.  No packages are used.

```
func <- function() {
    x <- rnorm(10)
    y <- runif(10)
    as.list(data.frame(x, y))
}
```

**2) mget** The above approach works if `x` and `y` have the same length but this approach works even if not.  Again, no packages are used.  This will output a named list of all the variables in `func2` but we could use
`mget(c("x", "y"))` if there were other variables in `func2` that we wanted to exclude.

```
func2 <- function() {
    x <- rnorm(10)
    y <- runif(10)
    mget(ls())
}
```

Although these idioms eliminate listing `x` and `y` twice (or even at all) in practice I think `list(x = x, y = y)` may be clearer.

Comment: I like this solution; I actually use `mget(ls())` to get some functions to dump all created objects into the output, but somehow I never thought about using it for this exact purpose. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tibble::lst`, which works also for unequal number of elements

```
func <- function() {
  x <- rnorm(3)
  y <- runif(2)
  out <- tibble::lst(x, y)
  return(out)
}

func()

# $x
#  [1]  0.04829009 -0.14348606  0.18524324
# 
# $y
#  [1] 0.1486643 0.5511159
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eapply`:

```
func <- function() {
    x <- rnorm(10)
    y <- runif(10)
    eapply(.GlobalEnv, I)[c("x","y")] 
}
```

or `sapply` with `get`:

```
func <- function() {
    x <- rnorm(10)
    y <- runif(10)
    sapply(c("x","y"), get, simplify = FALSE)
}
```